# Confused about creating mdf file

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a window project. I am required to add Service based database. I have also added one.

After that I created a new table with few records. Visual studio prompted me where to store it. Then I saved it on the desktop.

But it's not a `.mdf` file, rather it's a SQL Server query file (`.sql`).

I was expecting a `.mdf` file.

What am I doing wrong? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: What is inside the *.sql file?

Comment: Can't reproduce - create new Winforms app, add new "Service-based database" -> causes a `database1.mdf` to be added to my project.